# append fails when target a class auto-generated by cms system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help on the following.

The only way to solve this is be able to target the class. else what i am trying will not work. (I need to **append** some buttons behind the input field)
The cms system generate the code for the input class itself. (apparently added on load screen)
somehow there is now way i can target this with jquery…? or i just miss some skill be able to do so?

my jquery code:

```
$(".theInput").append($addButtons);
```

when i change `.theInput` with a other **class**, all working, but .*theInput* is just not WORKING.

NEED HELP

auto-generated by the cms system where i have totally no control to adjust it.

```
<td class="system">
<div class="cell">
<input onchange="some long code" class="theInput" type="text" value="1" /></div>

<div class="cell">
<input onchange="some long code" class="theInput" type="text" value="1" /></div>

<div class="cell">
<input onchange="some long code" class="theInput" type="text" value="1" /></div>

and so on. 
</td>
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should leave a note explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "behind the inputs", but you can't really append something to an input.  Append adds the element inside, and there is no inside for an input.  If you want to add something after the input you could do:

```
$(".theInput").after($addButtons);
```

Comment: Hi Kingjiv! Thanks! I am new to this and was used to use append for div and span. Now I know you have to use after when using input fields ! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you wrapped the code in a

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".theInput").append($addButtons);
});
```

You have to wait for the Dom to be loaded until you can target elements

Comment: Hi Samccone!, 
thanks for your input!! The script is loaded properly. Kingjiv provided the right answer. Thanks for thinking with me!